# collapse_rows is not collapsed and updating packages does not fix

Tags: kableextra

This script does not work for me. The table outputted does not have collapsed rows. I already updated all my packages. Can someone verify?

```
remove(list=ls())

library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

collapse_rows_dt <- data.frame(C1 = c(rep("a", 10), rep("b", 5)),
                 C2 = c(rep("c", 7), rep("d", 3), rep("c", 2), rep("d", 3)),
                 C3 = 1:15,
                 C4 = sample(c(0,1), 15, replace = TRUE))
kbl(collapse_rows_dt, align = "c") %>%
  kable_paper(full_width = F) %>%
  column_spec(1, bold = T) %>%
  collapse_rows(columns = 1:2, valign = "top")
```

The output looks like this

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a picture of your table? Thanks

Comment: I updated with photo

Comment: This is very weird. The code runs fine for me. Could you please provide your `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: sessionInfo() attached

Answer (score 8):

It [looks like](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/595) an upstream change to rvest introduced a bug in kableExtra 1.3.4. The fix isn't on CRAN yet but you can get it with a development build:

```
devtools::install_github(repo="haozhu233/kableExtra", ref="a6af5c0")
```

Comment: This works perfecly

Comment: This is still not resolved in 2023 and the above works.