# why collapse row from kableExtra package not working

Tags: r, dplyr, kableextra

I want to collapse rows which are duplicated as in the [example](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html#Grouped_Columns__Rows)

```
collapse_rows_dt <- data.frame(C1 = c(rep("a", 10), rep("b", 5)),
                 C2 = c(rep("c", 7), rep("d", 3), rep("c", 2), rep("d", 3)),
                 C3 = 1:15,
                 C4 = sample(c(0,1), 15, replace = TRUE))
kbl(collapse_rows_dt, align = "c") %>%
  kable_paper(full_width = F) %>%
  column_spec(1, bold = T) %>%
  collapse_rows(columns = 1:2, valign = "top")
```

I am getting the dataframe without any change  as output [image]

Any idea how to fix it ?
Is there any alternative way to collapse rows based on a column which has duplicated values ?

**The desired output:**
[image]

Comment: It's working for me with the code you posted. `kableExtra` version 1.3.4

Comment: I have same problem as OP. if I ran it on RStudio desktop it would not collapse the rows, while I ran it on a RStudio Server rows are collapsed as the example. Both environment using linux with same kableExtra version `1.3.4`.  I suspect this is due to some dependency missing but not sure what it is.

Comment: could you show me your desired output please!

Comment: @TarJae I've just edited the question to show the desired output.

Comment: I am having the same issues…

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, updating rvest package solved it for me

Comment: Do you mind explaining how this is related to the package kableExtra package?

Comment: Yes, sorry I'm a bit new here. I found another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66974669/collapse-rows-is-not-collapsed-and-updating-packages-does-not-fix) that suggests an upstream change to the rvest package back in March led to some change in functionality of the html_table function, a dependency of kableExtra::collapse_rows. The OP wasn't able to resolve the issue by updating rvest 1.0, but it resolved the issue for me when I updated rvest yesterday. I'm a bit confused as to why it worked because my package version is still 1.0 and the last update was back in March

Comment: Also the github development build they suggested didn't resolve the problem for me. I'm using kableExtra version 1.3.4.9000

Answer (score -1):

I confirm, same issue, updating rvest did the trick

Comment: Probably better to up-vote the answer you are confirming rather than posting a separate answer.